# HTTP Live Streaming detection on mobiles

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, http-live-streaming

I want to detect if a mobile phone/tablet can play HTTP Live Streaming (m3u8).

I'm currently testing with this script:

```
function isHLSEnabled() {
    var videoElement = document.createElement('video'),
        canPlayAppMpeg = videoElement.canPlayType('application/x-mpegURL'),
        canPlayAppleMpeg = videoElement.canPlayType('vnd.apple.mpegURL');

    return (
        (canPlayAppMpeg == 'probably' || canPlayAppMpeg == 'maybe')
        || (canPlayAppleMpeg == 'probably' || canPlayAppleMpeg == 'maybe')
    );
}
```

But it doesn't work well on some Samsung browsers (stock, dolphin, etc) - it returns false (because the canPlayTypes are empty strings) however it is able to play the video.

Are there any bulletproof(ish) solutions for detecting this kind of streaming support?

Comment: This is still a problem on Android 5.0 and Android 5.1 with stock browsers. Chrome plays ok.

Comment: I did not try this but does it work if you set the src of the video element to the stream src and check if the video is playing ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if there is bulletproof solution available at this point.

Using the video element's `canPlayType` method is the only thing that really 'works'. There are around +/- 5/6 media formats which have *oke* support from modern browsers.

So basically you create a list of formats you want to support and test from them. The `canPlayType` method allows you to also specify which codec. Which you should do since just testing for WebM might no lead to the desired result, an example:

`element.canPlayType('video/webm; codecs="vp9"')`.

After you do so you *should* generally get three different responses: "probably", "mabye" or ""(the empty string meaning: not supported).

Some resources you might find useful:

Mozilla provides a list of the main stream formats/codec:

[Mozilla Media Format List](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats)

Modernizr is framework that will test support for the majority of html5 video formats. You might also want to take a look at their source code for the html5 video detection.

[Modernizr HTML video detect](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/video.js)